# .success UncaughtSyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, heroku

I am truly baffled as to why I am receiving the 'Unexpected identifier' error with my code. The only thing that was changed recently was the URL.

I am working on a project and while waiting for my project partner to setup Heroku, I diverted to this fake API.

Here's my code:

```js
$('#username-submit').click(function() {
  var userlinks = $('.user-links')
  console.log('test');
  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET', //this is a GET git request
    url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com' //link to the API they created
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'user name'); //takes the username and authorizes it
      dataType: 'json',
        .success(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        })
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You forgot a `;` in your var declaration

Comment: @AndrewL True, but not causing the problem-it'd be optional there, no? The  issue is in the params being sent to the Ajax function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the beforeSend handler a little bit wrong, or rather the brackets and the commas.

This should fix it:

```js
$('#username-submit').click(function() {
  var userlinks = $('.user-links');
  console.log('test');
  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET', //this is a GET git request
    url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com', //link to the API they created
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'user name'); //takes the username and authorizes it
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

It also seems you're not using `userlinks`.

And to be frank, I doubt that "only the url changed" - the original version you've posted could never have worked in the first place.

Comment: Thanks very much!  That fixed the problem.  I haven't used the `userlinks` just yet because I plan on adding it in later to create content.